# how to prevent our process to be killed by Android System while low memory in MileStone?

Tags: android

how to prevent our process to be killed by Android System while low memory?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should not do that, and properly implement the lifecycle methods instead.  Are you absolutely sure your application needs to do that?

Comment: yes,my app always restart in milestone,it annoys me much.And i use Activity.setPersistent(true) does not work fine in milestone, any suggestions?

Comment: Why does that "annoy" you? That's exactly how the system is supposed to work, which is why the system provides you with the means to save and restore state.

Comment: thanks,but my app is a persistent app that should stay on Android,is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Services has higher priority than Activities.And it will be restarted automatically when android get enough resources.
If your app does not need user interaction continuously,I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to run in the background, you need a Service. A Service is less likely to be killed by the OS than a background Activity. Still you should expect that it will be killed, that is the design of Android. You can use the AlarmManager to frequently restart a Service if it has been killed, so that very little time passes without your Service running.